# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError error while rendering xcom_pull template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, jinja2, google-cloud-composer

currently on my project our Cloud Composer airflow version has been upgraded from v2.2.5 to v2.5.1 and since then I experiencing this error in some of my active DAGs

```
[2023-07-05, 00:40:16 UTC] {abstractoperator.py:609}
ERROR - Exception rendering Jinja template for task 'start_bulk', 
field 'skip_message'. 
Template: "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=['prevState_'+ti.task_id], key='skip_message')[0] }}"
        
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError:
airflow.models.xcom.LazyXComAccess object has no element 0
```

But when I tried removing the index [0] it worked!!
wanted to understand about this behavior and are there any changes in jijna template library regarding the xcoms in airflow releases/upgrades following my cloud composer airflow version.

code:

```
inside prevState function:
# can return False if the DAG has to skip the following task (pushing xcom)
kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='skip_message', value=skip_message)
return False  # can return False if the DAG has to skip the following task


class CustomPythonOperator(PythonOperator):
    template_fields = {'skip_condition', 'skip_message'} | set(PythonOperator.template_fields)

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, skip_condition, skip_message, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.skip_condition = skip_condition
        self.skip_message = skip_message
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def execute(self, context) -> Optional[str]:
        print("Check if the BulkAPI can be skipped")
        if self.skip_condition == "True":
            print("start custom PythonOperator")
            return super().execute(context)
        else:
            raise AirflowSkipException(self.skip_message)

        
#Start GKE workloads
start_update_operator = CustomPythonOperator(
task_id=task_name,
provide_context=True,
python_callable=start_and_update,
op_args=[DATASET, TABLE, USE_CASE, use_case_data],
skip_condition="{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=['prevState_'+ti.task_id])[0] }}",
skip_message="{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=['prevState_'+ti.task_id], key='skip_message')[0] }}",
# trigger_rule="all_done",
dag=dag)
```

Comment: can you please share the jinja line in your code (not just the error) ?

Comment: yeah, edited the question added the piece of code!